# Returning List<Object> to variables;

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio-2.2

I am doing a room database

```
    @Query("SELECT distinct UserID FROM USER WHERE CovidStat=='T'")
    public List<USER> checkCovid();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT PID,VisitDate FROM USER_PLACE,USER WHERE User.UserID=USER_PLACE.UID AND UID=(:UID)")
    int selectCovidPlace(int UID);
```

I wanted checkCovid() to return UserID where CovidStat='T' and I wanted to put the ID into selectCovidPlace to identify which place that ID been to. The problem is that checkCovid would return me a list instead of 1 variable since its not only 1 person who would have CovidStat='T', but im not sure that how can I put a list into selectCovidPlace().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SQLite. But the SQL syntax should be generic.

How about use `IN` statement?

like this `... WHERE User.UserID=USER_PLACE.UID AND UID IN (:UID)")`

And then you can pass `List` as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use [IN clause](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) as below:

```
 @Query("SELECT DISTINCT PID,VisitDate FROM USER_PLACE,USER WHERE User.UserID=USER_PLACE.UID AND UID IN (:UIDs)")
    int selectCovidPlace(List<Integer> UIDs);
```